# karma unit testing does not works after the void function excuted

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

> unit testing code in spec.ts

```
  it('Should test LoadMenus method', () => {
            let arrays = [{ "Id": 1, "MenuType": "A00", "MenuName": "Search", "UserDetail": { "UserName": "rajendranra" } 
            alert(11);// executed  
                        this.modalNota.LoadMenus(arrays, 'A00', 'A', '0');
            alert(12);// does not execute
            expect(this.modalNota.cocmenuitems[0].MenuName).toBe('Search');
        });
```

> Component method which am testing

```
LoadMenus(lstMenu, menustring, submenustartstring, submenuendstring) {
        alert(menustring);
        this.subitems = [];
        let menu = lstMenu.find(myObj => myObj.MenuType === menustring);
        if (menu !== null) {
            this.menufilter = lstMenu.filter(myObj => myObj.MenuType.startsWith(submenustartstring))
                .filter(x => x.MenuType.endsWith(submenuendstring));
            if (this.menufilter.length > 1) {
                for (let menuType = 0; menuType < this.menufilter.length; menuType++) {
                    if (this.menufilter[menuType].MenuType !== menustring) {
                        this.subitems.push({
                            label: this.menufilter[menuType].MenuName,
                            routerLink: [this.GetLink(this.menufilter[menuType].MenuName)]
                        });
                    }
                }
                alert(menu.MenuName);
                this.cocmenuitems.push({ label: menu.MenuName, routerLink: [this.GetLink(menu.MenuName)], items: this.subitems });
            } else {
                alert(menu.MenuName);
                this.cocmenuitems.push({ label: menu.MenuName, routerLink: [this.GetLink(menu.MenuName)] });
            }
        }
    }
```

This unit test showing the result is failed. the main problem is **Alert `alert(12);` does not fire**. Why my alert(12) does not hit after this `this.modalNota.LoadMenus(arrays, 'A00', 'A', '0');` component code is executed??

> Am struggling  a whole day for this. kindly give me the solution.

Comment: does your `expect` fire?

Comment: yes, but I can't see the alert(12).